# Use hard disks with different file system encoding on the same Linux machine, feasible?

Tags: linux, unicode, filesystems

As we know, Linux and Unix style filesystems store file name as byte stream, as apposed to Unicode streams on Windows NTFS/FAT.

So there is the question. If I get an old hard disk(from around 2002) with non-ASCII filenames encoded as "gbk" on its Ext3 partitions, and I want to attach that old disk to my modern Linux(utf8-encoded filenames) so that I can copy the old files out, **preserving filename character meaning** .

Then what's the best practice to do that?

Explaination from a programmers perspective is specially welcome.

Comment: I have an old laptop that I don't use anymore, but it has Linux and Windows XP and when Linux is running it can read the Windows partition. Why not just plug it in and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you. I believe it can, because Windows explicitly/definitly stores Unicode character on FS so there is no ambiguation. I just want to know how guys in pure Linux world can cope with that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Most Linux programs don't care about disk or mountpoint boundaries, and use the same encoding for all file names everywhere.

However, most utilities *still* treat filenames as byte strings, so there should be no problem with copying or using files named in weird encodings. (For example, I renamed a few my files to ISO-8859-13 and I can still open them in command-line or GNOME programs, although KDE has troubles.)

You can use tools such as `convmv` to rename all files to UTF-8 names – either in your copy, or directly on the original disk:

```
convmv -f gbk -t utf-8 -r /mnt/old-disk
```

---

(On Linux, it is possible to write overlay filesystems using FUSE, which could present the files from a given path using a different name encoding. I don't know if such a filesystem exists, though. `bindfs` has a similar purpose, but it only translates file ownership/permissions. Either way, I'm sticking with my recommendation to just convert all names to UTF-8.)

Comment: Thank you for referring to ``convmv``, and I find it's a perl script. After some trying, I'm starting to worry about its reliability. ``convmv``'s processing seems to rename on a file basis, instead of on a directory basis. So, when some gbk file name sequence happens to be UTF8 sequence( ``touch $(echo '0xE7 0x94 0xB5 0xE8 0x84 0x91'|xxd -r).txt`` ), it says **Skipping, already UTF-8**.

Comment: Use the `--nosmart` option. (The tool is most commonly used for fixing ISO-8859- filenames, which don't have this problem.)

Comment: Thank you. ``--nosmart`` does what I mean. But I'm not very sure whether convmv does it on a directory basis or a file basis. The man page seems not to be explicit on this. I can't figure it out myself due to not knowing Perl yet.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me. When I run:

convmv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf8 R*kurr*

It says:
Skipping, already UTF-8: ./RÃ¶kkurrÃ³

Adding "--nosmart" makes it say:

mv "./RÃ¶kkurrÃ³"       "./RÃÂ¶kkurrÃÂ³"

I think it should be "Rökkurró". I don't know why the filename is broken... the file was from windows.

Comment: And this was fun too, to guess the encoding, but didn't find one that works.

for e in $(convmv --list); do convmv -f "$e" -t utf8 --nosmart R*kurr* 2>&1 | grep "mv"; done

Comment: @Peter: In your case, the name is UTF-8, but encoded _twice_ (a program mistakenly thinking that the input isn't UTF-8 yet). Therefore you must convert it in the _opposite_ direction. Try `convmv -f utf-8 -t iso8859-1`.

Comment: @Peter: [Notice how each accented letter corresponds to _multiple_ gibberish characters, always starting with something similar to `Ã`; a sign that each UTF-8 byte is being interpreted in one of the old single-byte charsets. It's a very distinctive pattern.]

Comment: @Peter: However, **before doing anythimg, make sure** that the _filename_ is incorrect, and _not_ your terminal misinterpreting the correct filename. Run `printf 'R\xc3\xb6kkurr\xc3\xb3\n'` and see if it shows up correctly. If it doesn't, do not rename anything.

Comment: @grawity. Looks like you are right. It worked to convert from utf8 to latin1. I wonder how this was ever messed up ... all I did was get these files from a windows machine by putting the disk into a Linux machine and cp -a from there. So I assumed it was some windows format.